# Soap Header variable in BPEL

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I am using SOA suite and developing a BPEL process. I want to add a header to the request going to a partner link. I have added a variable with a messageType picked from WSDL of partner. Used Header tab and added this variable to request.

But while running, I couldn't see this header in request xml. The variable which I have created is properly initialized and holding the value as expected.

Tools: SOA, BPEL 1.1, JDeveloper 11.1.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the desired header as shown here
http://chintanblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/soa-11g-bpel-soap-header.html

Comment: I found the solution for this. It is same as the one given in your link.